# Is it possible to default an output directory for R Scripts in QGIS 3.4.4?

Tags: qgis, r, qgis-3, rqgis

I am currently running R Scripts through the Processing R Provider plugin on QGIS 3.4.4.

I was wondering if it is possible to to set a default file path for your vector output that is the same as your project home in the QGIS project you have open?

e.g. `##Output=output vector ("Project directory")` - I know this doesn't work but hopefully it gives a better idea of what I'm after.

[image]

This is so you do not have to browse to your project file every time you want to save your output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately that's not supported - it might be worth filing a Feature Request on the QGIS tracker to see if it can be implemented in a future release.